# how to integrate UnityAds SDK in swift?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, ads, appdelegate

When I call UnityAds.startWithGameId("") in the AppDelegate under:

```
application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions
```

I get this error: 
'UnityAds' does not conform to protocol 'StringLiteralConvertible'

how can i fix it? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem integrating UnityAds with my Swift project. I solved it creating a Bridging File and doing an import of UnityAds's library:

```
#import <UnityAds/UnityAds.h>
```

**Create a Bridging File:** https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html

Then you can use all available methods calling a sharedInstance object of UnityAds, for example:

```
UnityAds.sharedInstance().setTestMode(true)
```

or

```
UnityAds.sharedInstance().startWithGameId(UnityAdsID)
```

Everything is working fine in my game and I can play videos and show ads without problems :) I hope this can be useful for you!

Comment: Since this took me a while to figure out reading Apple's docs.  To create the bridge file in most simple cases: 1. Add a new H file, I called mine bridge.h.  2. Under Build Settings, Swift Compiler - Code Generation, under "Objective C Bridging Header", type the path to your file.  If you used my name, and put in the root of project, you'd just type "bridge.h" in this option.  That's it, now you can use the classes in any swift file in the project without any imports.  bridge.h just needs the one import statement shown above.